# Group of order 616 solvable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, solvable-groups

Proof that all groups of order 616 are solvable.

I already know (counting elements) that at least one of the 2-, 7- or 11-sylow-subgroups has to be normal. Unfortunately i can not figure out which one. I think it might be possible to calculate each and every possibility but hope that someone can instead help with a clever way of solving this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are either $\;1\;$ or $\;56\;$ Sylow $\;11\,-$ subgroup. If the latter, then we already have $\;56\cdot10=560\;$ elements of order $\;11\;$. If the Sylow $\;7\,-$ subgroup isn't normal, then there are $\;8\;$ of them, which give $\;8\cdot6=48\;$ elements of order $\;7\;$, and thus there are left $\;616-560-48=8\;$ elements, which must thus **a unique** Sylow $\;2\,-$ subgroup.

Thus, there's always a *normal* Sylow subgroup, and taking the quotient by it we get a group of order $\;56,\,77\;$ or $\;88\;$, all of which are solvable. Of course, the normal Sylow subgroup is also solvable so we're done.

Comment: Random question (sorry if it's a stupid one): why do all elements of a Sylow $11$-subgroup (say), apart from the identity, have order 11?

Comment: @Alex.F Because it is a group of **prime order** and because, of course,  the order of any element in a finite group divides the group's order (Lagrange's Theorem)

Comment: D'oh! Thank you so much!